# Cut and print specific characters in awk

Tags: awk

I have these data in a file:

```
one,1,/home/steven/Transformation/users.txt
two,2,/home/steven/Transformation/users.txt
```

And I want ouptut like this:

```
one,1,users.txt
two,2,users.txt
```

How to handle this using awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method1

```
awk -F "," 'OFS=","{print $1,$2,substr($NF,29)}'  filename
```

Method2:

```
sed "s/\/.*\///g" filename
```

Method3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r'/.*/')
p=open('p.txt','r')
for i in p:
    print re.sub(k,"",i).strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F '[,/]' '{print $1","$2","$NF}'
```

Or with using `OFS`

```
awk -F '[,/]' -v OFS=',' '{print $1, $2, $NF}'
```

Comment: Since you're using FS you could also use OFS: `awk -F '[,/]' -v OFS=',' '{print $1, $2, $NF}'`

Comment: `awk -F / '{print $1 $NF}' `

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sed`:

```
sed 's;/.*/;;' file
```

Or with `cut` and `sed`:

```
cut -d / -f1,5 file | sed 's;/;;'
```

`cut` and `tr`

```
tr '/' ',' < file | cut -d , -f1,2,7
```

Output:

```
one,1,users.txt
two,2,users.txt
```

---

For [this input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571673/cut-and-print-specific-characters-in-awk/571678?noredirect=1#comment1065518_571678):

```
/one,/1,/home/steven/Transformation/users.txt 
/two,/2,/home/steven/Transformation/users.txt
```

The command:

```
sed -E 's;(.*,)/.*/;\1;' file
```

Output:

```
/one,/1,users.txt 
/two,/2,users.txt
```

Comment: and how if i have a "/" on the 1st and 2nd but i don't want to escape them?but only the "/" on the 3rd row?

Comment: @NickAndoniaina could show post a sample of what you mean?

Comment: The data in the file:
/one,/1,/file
/two,/2,/file
and the desired output i want:
/one,/1,file
/two,/2,file
The "/" of the 3rd row only is escaped

Comment: /one,/1,/home/steven/Transformation/users.txt
/two,/2,/home/steven/Transformation/users.txt
and i want this output:
/one,/1,users.txt
/two,/2,users.txt

Comment: @NickAndoniaina I updated the answer with the new input.